# AngularJS is it possible to watch changes in ng-repeat?

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible to highlight change in value that is generated with ng-repeat, from external JSON file that updates every 5sec. with $interval

This is the controller:

```
app.controller('main', function($scope,$http,$interval,$routeParams){
  $scope.pageParam = $routeParams.pageParam;

  function getJSON(){
    var url = "json.php";
    $http.get(url)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.matches    = data;
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error');
        });
  }; 
  getJSON();
  $interval(getJSON,5000);

});
```

And in the HTML, I use ng-repeat to print the data from $scope.matches, if some of the data that I print changes in the $scope.matches I want it to be highlighted.

```
<div class="col-xs-4 odd">{{ match.odds }}</div>
```

So if the match.odds is 5.6, and on the next interval changes to 5.9 I want to change color.

[Sample of the JSON file](http://pastebin.com/tyFurs79)

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
$scope.$watchCollection(matches, function(newMatches, oldMatches){...});
```

Comment: I approve it, but please provide some explanation for such short answers in future.

Comment: Its not much helpful, i will need to compare by ID, some attribute that has id+type, and I will need to watch that attribute
example: 13245+field1;13245+field2
I hope you understand me

Comment: If you want to watch for changes to the `matches` array, this is how to do it. `getJSON()` replaces the array with a new one so you'll have to $watch the whole array for changes. Without adding any JS there might be a way to animate changes by adding a `track by` expression to your ng-repeat (to prevent each DOM element re-rendering) and then use css to animate the changes (not totally sure about that part).